# Normalized sinc(at)

Tags: signal-processing

I came across the definition of the sinc function when it is normalized as sinc(t)= sin(pi.t)/pi.t. So if we scale the argument of the normalized sinc function as sinc(at), will that equal sin(a.pi.t)/a.pi.t? Can anyone pls explain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. It might be easier to see if you write $sinc(as)$, and then replaced $t$ everywhere in the definition with $as$.